# javascript callback after the interval has executed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I am using the custom interval function to ensure that the function execution has finished first until it is run the next time. In general I do the following I check the redis database and check if the job was executed by the sidekiq. If it was executed I make a request to database to fetch the information if it was written to it, I run this function 10 times if after 10th time there is no data I resolve undefined. I wonder whether the solution I have right now can be somehow improved.

```
 const interval = (func, wait, times) => {
    const interv = function(w, t){
      return () => {
        if (typeof t === 'undefined' || t-- > 0) {
          setTimeout(interv, w);
          try {
            func.call(null);
          }
          catch (e) {
            t = 0;
            throw e.toString();
          }
        }
      };
    }(wait, times);
    setTimeout(interv, wait);
  };

    let intervalCount = 0;
    interval(() => {
      intervalCount++;
      redisClient.lrange('queue:default', 0, -1, (err, results) => {
        const job = results.find((element) => { return JSON.parse(element).jid === jobId; });
        if (job === undefined) {
          checkDatabase(personId).then((result) => {
            if (result) {
              resolve(checkDatabase(personId));
            } else if (intervalCount >= 10) {
              resolve(undefined);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }, 1500, 10);
```

Comment: you can make a "done()" by adding an `else` to `if (typeof t === 'undefined' || t-- > 0)`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum resolve is 'bluebird' promise I have not included it in this code snippet.

Comment: @dandavis that's a good idea I will give it a try. I just want to remove the counter else block `if (intervalCount >= 10) {
              resolve(undefined);
            }`

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri promises are a one time thing, they get resolved _once_.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yeap they are, so in my case I want to resolve the promise after the interval ran 10 times or the checkDatabase returned the result value

Comment: Ok, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're using modern NodeJS and you mentioned you're using promises and bluebird so let's use a modern solution using generators and bluebird.

You should not be using the promise constructor very often at all. You can promisify the redis API and make your life easier:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(require("redis")); // now redis is promisified


var pollAndResolve = Promise.coroutine(function* pollAndResolve () {
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       yield Promise.delay(1500); // wait 1500 ms
       yield redisClient.lrangeAsync('queue:default', 0, -1); // since we promisifed
       const job = results.find((element) => JSON.parse(element).jid === jobId);
       if (result) return yield checkDatabase(personId);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot, one more thing can you please point me to some resources to get NodeJS game improved :)

Comment: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html